# Configured repositories failed on CentOS 7

Tags: centos7, repository

I am using CyberPanel (OpenLiteSpeed ) on CentOS 7, when I am trying to update through Terminal Command then an error message comes and is as:
[root@server ~]# yum update -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/x86_64/metalink | 7.6 kB 00:00:00

- base: repo1.dal.innoscale.net
- epel: d2lzkl7pfhq30w.cloudfront.net
- extras: mirror.cs.vt.edu
- updates: mirror.atlanticmetro.net
  https://rep.cyberpanel.net/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's Certificate has expired."
  Trying other mirror.
  It was impossible to connect to the CentOS servers.
  This could mean a connectivity issue in your environment, such as the requirement to configure a proxy,
  or a transparent proxy that tampers with TLS security, or an incorrect system clock.
  You can try to solve this issue by using the instructions on https://wiki.centos.org/yum-errors
  If above article doesn't help to resolve this issue please use https://bugs.centos.org/.

One of the configured repositories failed (CyberPanel),
and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.
2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
   upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
   distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
   packages for the previous distribution release still work).
3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
   yum --disablerepo=CyberPanel ...
4. Disable the repository permanently, so yum won't use it by default. Yum
   will then just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it
   again or use --enablerepo for temporary usage:

yum-config-manager --disable CyberPanel
or
subscription-manager repos --disable=CyberPanel

5. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
   Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
   so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
   slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
   compromise:

yum-config-manager --save --setopt=CyberPanel.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from CyberPanel: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://rep.cyberpanel.net/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl#60 - "Peer's Certificate has expired."
[root@server ~]#

As well when I am running this Command to get repolist, then
[root@server ~]# yum repolist
repo id
CyberPanel
base/7/x86_64
copr:copr.fedorainfracloud.org:copart:restic/x86_64
dovecot-2.3-latest/7/x86_64
epel/x86_64
extras/7/x86_64
gf/x86_64
litespeed/7/x86_64
litespeed-update/7/x86_64
lux/7
mariadb
powerdns-auth-42/7/x86_64
updates/7/x86_64
repolist: 29,666

When I am contacted to CyberPanel support forums then I get the reply " Remove this repository it is no longer needed."
I am new with my VPS and Terminal command, so I need help to fix it.
Please help me through the correct Terminal Command so that I can fix this issue.
Thanks

Comment: You can't fix this issue because it is CyberPanel's TLS certificate that has expired. Their support gave you bad information, and you should go back there. Only they can fix their web server.

Comment: @MichaelHampton please see the conversation made with CyberPanel support forums here: https://forums.cyberpanel.net/discussion/5418/cyberpanel-configured-repositories-failed and the reply given by the Administrator (https://forums.cyberpanel.net/profile/usmannasir) as well as he referred me to use this guide: use this guide https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/product-guides/dedicated-hosting/delete-repos-centos/

Comment: If the repository is really no longer necessary, as he said, then you can just delete it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, How can I delete it, actually I need the Terminal Command that I need to delete it. Truly Can I use:  yum remove CyberPanel  or any other. Please help me.

Comment: Hello @MichaelHampton, Please help me as I can't want to do anything wrong that may made bad impact on my VPS, so please review it and tell me the correct terminal command w.r.t. repo name so that I can do it. Thanks